# execute shell function on a command in make variable

Tags: shell, makefile

In my makefile, I am trying to capture the output from a shell function call on a make variable containing the command string without success.  When I run the shell function on the string directly, it works.  I don't understand what the difference is between running the shell function on the command string versus running the shell function on a make variable containing the command string.

```
PG_CONFIG = "/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config/"

PG_INCLUDE1 = $(shell $$PG_CONFIG)
PG_INCLUDE2 = $(shell /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config --includedir-server)

.PHONY: print

print:
    @echo "PG_CONFIG="$(PG_CONFIG)
    @echo "PG_INCLUDE1="$(PG_INCLUDE1)
    @echo "PG_INCLUDE2="$(PG_INCLUDE2)
```

The output is:

```
$make -f Makefile.test print
PG_CONFIG=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config/
PG_INCLUDE1=
PG_INCLUDE2=/usr/pgsql-9.4/include/server
```

Comment: try `PG_INCLUDE1 = $(shell $(PG_CONFIG))`

Answer (score 3):

As it stands in [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables-in-Recipes.html):

> Variable and function references in recipes have identical syntax and
>   semantics to references elsewhere in the makefile. They also have the
>   same quoting rules: if you want a dollar sign to appear in your
>   recipe, you must double it (‘$$’). For shells like the default shell,
>   that use dollar signs to introduce variables, it’s important to keep
>   clear in your mind whether the variable you want to reference is a
>   make variable (use a single dollar sign) or a shell variable (use two
>   dollar signs).

The `$$` is replaced with a single dollar. In your example:

```
PG_INCLUDE1 = $(shell $$PG_CONFIG)
```

becomes:

```
PG_INCLUDE1 = $(shell $PG_CONFIG)
```

Next, `$PG_CONFIG` is executed in shell just as if you typed it in the terminal. And as there is no `PG_CONFIG` variable defined in the current subshell `$PG_CONFIG` is replaced with nothing. However, if you defined `PG_CONFIG` environment variable before running `make` it would work as you wished with `$$` in `Makefile`:

```
$ export PG_CONFIG="aoeuidhtn"
$ make
PG_CONFIG=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config/
PG_INCLUDE1=aoeuidhtn
```

Comment: Always use `:=` when assigning values to variables within make files.

Comment: @mhradek: Because?

Comment: Per `https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html` the colon tells the processor to only read and assign once.

Comment: First, link you posted describes an ancient version of `make` -
3.79.1 was released in 2000 https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make.  Second, you
said what `:=` does but didn't explain why should it *always* be used?

Comment: Same applies: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html Perhaps _always_ is too strong of a word. How about "Consider using simple assignment over recursive assignment whenever possible to be explicit and avoid inadvertent assignment issues".

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems.  The definition of PG_CONFIG ends with a "/" so it is being treated as a directory.  And your variable reference in PG_INCLUDE1 should be $(PG_CONFIG) not $$PG_CONFIG.

Try this:

```
PG_CONFIG = "/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config"

PG_INCLUDE1 = $(shell $(PG_CONFIG))
PG_INCLUDE2 = $(shell /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config --includedir-server)

.PHONY: print

print:
    @echo "PG_CONFIG="$(PG_CONFIG)
    @echo "PG_INCLUDE1="$(PG_INCLUDE1)
    @echo "PG_INCLUDE2="$(PG_INCLUDE2)
```

Comment: There's also no reason to keep the make variables outside the quoted string in the shell lines (they can even go inside a single quoted string).

Comment: Your example yields `Makefile:9: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: Nevermind. Needed to replace the spaces before @echo with tabs.